# Call to a member function delete() on bool on Destroy method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I got this error: `Call to a member function delete() on bool`

Out of my code, which is:

```
public function destroy($id){
    $user= Auth::user();
    $descuento = Descuento::with('ventas')->where('id',$id)->first();

    foreach( $descuento as $descuentos ) {
        if( isset($descuentos->ventas->descuento_id) ) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'No es posible eliminar el descuento ya que fue utilizado'], 500);
        } else {
            $descuentos->delete();
        }
}
```

Does anyone knows why I'm getting this error? I've been struggling all day because of this.

Comment: foreach( $descuento as $descuentos ) { => This is wrong, you are only selecting one record from database and no need of iteration. If the record is not found first() will return null.. So you can check with if(!empty())

Comment: A single `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` or null as returned by `->first()` **is not** iterable.

Comment: This is off-topic, but I'm not pleased with the `500` error response. Shouldn't it be `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY`? Even better, this check should instead be a Form validation rule ([exists:table,column](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exists)).

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Models _are_ iterable, `foreach(Model::first() as $column => $value)` (or `foreach(Model::first() as $model)`) actually works just fine. In this case, the iteration is `true/false->delete()`, which for obvious reasons is not valid, and triggers a 500 error.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, you're right, my bad . Models are iterable. Thanks for your clarification. Though, I hardly think that the response from the Model iteration is useful to the OP. `foreach( \App\Models\User::where("id", 1)->first() as $k => $v) {echo "$k => $v, ";}` returns `incrementing => 1, preventsLazyLoading => , exists => 1, wasRecentlyCreated => , timestamps => 1,`

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa That's correct  There aren't many (if any, really) real-world cases to iterate a single Model, as all that is doing is looping the various `public` properties of the Model, like `incrementing,` `timestamps`, etc. A better case is `foreach(Model::first()->toArray() as $column => $value) { echo $column. ' is: ' . $value; }`, which will show each column and value of said Model. But yeah, this is a simple mistake the OP made; if they simply omitted the `foreach()`, their code would have been mostly fine (with a few refactors in variable names, etc.) 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like this

```
<?php    
public function destroy($id){
$user= Auth::user();
$descuento = Descuento::with('ventas')->where('id',$id)->first();

if(!empty($descuento)){
  if(!empty($descuento->ventas->descuento_id) ) {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'No es posible eliminar el descuento ya que fue utilizado'], 500);
  } else {
    $descuento->delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need to do `if(!empty($descuento))`, a simple `if($descuento) { // code to delete }` works just fine; Models, if not `null`, are `truthy` enough to pass a simple check like that 

Comment: Also, if you ever see `where('id', $id)->first()`, replace that with `->find($id)` (or `->findOrFail()`, etc.); `->find()` is shorthand for `->where('id', $id)->first()` (`'id'` being automatically replaced with the specified `primary_key` for the Model)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `ventas` is a relationship of `descuento`. If that's the case and you are looking that `descuento` must has no `ventas` related in order to be deleteable,  then you could make your code clean by doing this:

```
public function destroy($id){
    $descuento = Descuento::whereDoesntHave('ventas')->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
    $descuento->delete();
}
```

`firstOrFail()` will throw a 404 exception if `descuento` has a `venta` related, otherwise deletion will proceed.

BTW, is a good practice to use english names, Laravel usually maps everything by looking for nouns names (Relationships, Policies, etc)